# Starting a screen while su'ed into another user from an alias isn't working

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, alias

```
minecraft@283823:~$ script /dev/null ; screen -t minecraft
  Script started, file is /dev/null
minecraft@283823:~$ exit
  Script done, file is /dev/null
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0' - please check.
```

My interpretation is I'm staying in the `script /dev/null` instead of running that to set up a new pts so I can screen as a su'ed user...

I'm testing my alias that does the same thing - `script /dev/null ; screen`. I tried doing this in a bash script the other day and I wound up with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This I believe is due to a safety feature that is present on Debian and Ubuntu distributions, if not most other Linux distributions. As previously mentioned a work around could be to change permissions of /dev/pts/* but I would **strongly** advice against it as it is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing the permission on /dev/pts/0?

```
 chmod 666 /dev/pts/0
```

and then trying what you want to do.